# Extract a section in url pattern using re.match

Tags: python, regex

In nodejs, i use regex to extract the sub-section under `tenant` in this url, `http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services`. It prints correctly, `sk`.

Code is,

```
var re = /(?:[\w\W]+)\/tenant\/([\w]+?)\/(?:[\w\W]*)/
var results = re.exec('http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services')
console.log(results[1])
```

I moved the code to python as,

```
import re
m = re.match(r"(?:\w\W+)tenant/(\w+)/(?:[\w\W]*)", "http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services")
m.group(1)
```

It throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Why doesn't it match one word that comes after `tenant`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findall/search should help you

findall

```
>>> m = re.findall(r"(?:\w\W+)tenant/(\w+)/(?:[\w\W]*)", "http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services")
>>> m
['sk']
```

search

```
>>> m = re.search(r"(?:\w\W+)tenant/(\w+)/(?:[\w\W]*)", "http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services")
>>> m.group(1)
'sk'
```

The reason match fails is because it tries to match it at beginning of string 
[re.match documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0) If zero or more characters at the
>   beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a
>   corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not
>   match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length
>   match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the
>   beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead
>   (see also search() vs. match()).

Answer (score 2):

`match` does not have `group` attribute. Try `search` instead-

```
>>>m = re.search(r"(tenant)/(\w+)/(\w+)", "http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services")
>>>m.group(1)
>>>'tenant'
>>>m.group(2)
>>>'sk'
>>>m.group(3)
>>>'services'
>>>m.groups()
>>>('tenant', 'sk', 'services')
```

Or try `re.split` that returns a regular list- `(?<!\\)/(?!=\\)` means find `/` that does not have `/` after or before- and split the text by it-

```
>>>re.split(r"(?<!\\)/(?!=\\)", "http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services")
>>>['http:', '', 'myServer:8000', 'api', 'running', 'tenant', 'sk', 'services']
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need regex in this case, [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is enough:

```
>>> url = 'http://myServer:8000/api/running/tenant/sk/services'
>>> l = url.split('/')
>>> l[l.index('tenant')+1]
'sk'
>>>
```